# Multiple fragments with different loadermanager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-loadermanager

I am fairly new to android development and have been searching for the solution for the past 4 hours.

I have 2 Fragments in an Activity and both of them uses different sqlite tables for data which will then be put into adapters to show within the fragment.

I'm using Loader manager created two different loaders (with different Ids) for two fragments. I'm defining Loader callback functions in each fragment. The problem is when I load the data using one fragment, in OnCreateLoader of that fragment return null data for the second Fragment.

here is the code I've implemented in one fragment:

```
    @Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    if (id==1){
        String[] projection = {
                NoticeTable.COLUMN_ID,NoticeTable.COLUMN_TITLE
        };
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
                NoticeContentProvider.ALL_NOTICE_URI, projection, null, null, null);
        return cursorLoader;
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

    switch (loader.getId()) {
        case 1:
            adapter.swapCursor(data);
            break;
        case 0:
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    switch (loader.getId()) {
        case 1:
            adapter.swapCursor(null);
            break;
        case 0:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put all of your LoaderManager functions inside each Fragment, you shouldn't have a problem. The setup would be like this:

```
public class FragOne extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {}
public class FragTwo extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {}
```

Then, you can initialize the loader inside the Fragment's onResume or something like that, so it'll work independently of the other Fragment.

I would like to add as a suggestion to use a constant variable for the loader id. I tend to do so like this:

```
public class FragOne extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
   private static final int FRAG_ONE_LOADER = 0;

   public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
      switch(loader.getId()) {
         case FRAG_ONE_LOADER:
            doStuff();
            break;
         default:
            break;
      }
   }
}
```

Since you've separated the logic into each fragment, FragmentOne will never see or have access to a loader with id `FRAG_TWO_LOADER`.

Comment: I was using loader manager from support library which was specific to an activity. Changed that to loader manager and its all working fine. Thanks!

By the way, is there any way we can apply support loader manager instead of loader manager in this case. One single loader manager specific to one Activity?

Comment: I suppose it's possible but I'm not exactly sure what you mean. When I think about it, each ListView is specific to each Fragment which is why I feel the Fragment should be responsible for it. If you wanted to put it in the Activity you can, just have two adapter instances and assign each adapter to the appropriate ListView, I think it could work with some tweaks.